# How to convert string into integer in WindowsPhone7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, type-conversion

I need to convert a string to an integer in windows Phone 7. I tried following code but my app crashed:

```
int val1 = Convert.ToInt16(str);
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Please edit your question to suppply details on the error you are getting, and the string that you are passing in.  Also, it is hard to see why this is Windows Phone related - this is a general .NET question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why does it crash? Do you get an errormessage? What is the actual value of *'str'*? Maybe the problem lies there. Also I would opt for ToInt32() as this returns an int, while ToInt16() returns a short. This will not give a problem but it looks more logic. And last, these methods will do the job:

```
int val1 = Convert.ToInt32("123");

int val2 = int.Parse("123");

int val3 = 0;
int.TryParse("123", out val3);
```

Comment: Here the string contains this value
 string str = cusseconds.ToString();

Comment: What?! How is that supposed to be of any help?

Comment: Oh ok, I thought this was a proposed solution or something, my bad.. :D Do you have an actual value of the variable? Try debugging/setting a breakpoint and evaluate the value of the variable to get it. And see if it is in a correct format to convert to an int.

Comment: You are correct sir, the string is the problem sir, thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

To convert string to integer, use

```
string text = "500";
int num = int.Parse(text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
string str = "155";
int retVal;
if(int.TryParse(str, out retVal))
{
   // You can now code with it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try Convert.ToInt32(str)

Think this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think `int.TryParse` is the way to go. This way you will get to know if the parsing was successful or not by checking the return value. The advantage is since it does not throw any exception you don't have to write any error handling code which makes it simpler and less error prone. I do not personally like code that throws a lot of exceptions as one might easily goof up whilst handling them.

If you are sure to use this on a 32 bit platform, you can try `Int32.TryParse()` , or if 64- bit platform you may use `Int64.TryParse()`